# Continuity of Translation and Dilation on $L^p$ spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, lp-spaces, harmonic-analysis

Let us consider any $f \in L^p(U)$, where $U \subset \mathbb R^n$ is open,
and $1 < p < \infty$.

We know the translation operator
$f(x) \mapsto f(x+a)$
and the dilation operator
$f(x) \mapsto f(s x)$,
where $a \in \mathbb R^n$ and $s \in \mathbb R^n$.

**Questions:**

i) Under which conditions on $U$ and $p$ are translation and dilation bounded, when $a$ and $s$ are fixed, and what is the norm?

ii) Conversely, when $f$ is fixed, under what conditions are translation and dilation continuous in the parameters, and how good is that continuity (like locally Hölder)?

Comment: This question might be of interest: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/842937/

Comment: It seems that $s$ should be in $\Bbb R$, not in $\Bbb R^n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the following.

I will consider that  $s\in\Bbb R$, not in $\Bbb R^n$, because I don’t understand what is $sx\in\Bbb R^n$

The correctness of the definition of the operator imposes restrictions on the set $U$: $U+a\subset U$ or $sU\subset U$.  Or we may for each function $f\in L^p(U)$ consider its extension in $L^p(\Bbb R^n)$ such that $f|(\Bbb R^n\setminus U)\equiv 0$ and to deal with this extension.

i) The translation operator $T_a$ preserves the norm:

$$\| f\|^p=\int_U f(x)^pd\mu=\int_{\Bbb R^n} f(x)^pd\mu=\int_U f(x+a)^pd\mu=\|T_a f\|^p.$$

The dilation operator $D_s$ has norm $|s|^{-n/p}$:

$$\|f\|^p=\int_U f(x)^pd\mu=\int_{\Bbb R^n} f(x)^pd\mu=|s|^{-n}\int_{\Bbb R^n} f(sx)^pd\mu=|s|^{-n}\|D_sf\|^p.$$

ii) I hope that similarly to answers to a question pointed by @saz, we can show that $\lim_{r \to r_0} \|T_rf−T_{r_0}f\|_{L_p} =0$ and $\lim_{s \to s_0} \|D_sf−D_{s_0}f\|_{L_p}=0$.