# A help in demonstration of $\lim$ 0f lebesgue integral

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

If $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R^n})$ $1\leq p < \infty$ then prove $\displaystyle\lim_{|h|\to 0} \|f(x + h) - f(x)\|_p = 0$.

I had tried to prove the continuity a.e. of $\|f(x + h) - f(x)\|_p$, then could pass the $\lim$. This way is good or there is other more simple?

Comment: This question has already good answers here :
[Show that $\lim\limits_{r\to0} ∥Trf−f∥_{L^p}=0$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/842937/show-that-lim-r-to-0-t-rf%E2%88%92f-l-p-0?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Since $f$ is not continuous, I believe you will have to use the "standard framework" to prove this. Specifically, I mean that you should first establish the claim for simple functions $\varphi$ and then use this to establish the claim for more general functions.

Comment: How would you do it for $\chi_E?$

Answer (score 0):

Its easier to prove it first for $C^\infty_c$. For these functions we have mean value theorem(for $\Bbb R^n$ its only  an inequality), valid for every $x,h$   $$|f(x+h) - f(x)| ≤ |\nabla f(x_0)h| ≤ ‖∇ f‖_∞ |h|$$
So if $\text{supp }f = U$,
$$ ∫_{\mathbb R^n} |f(x) - f(x+h)|^p \ \text dx ≤ \mu(U )‖ ∇ f‖^p_∞ |h|^p → 0 $$
Then conclude by density; choose $f_n$ smooth compactly supported with $f_n → f ∈ L^p$, and $n$ large we obtain
$$‖ f(x+h) - f(x) ‖_p ≤ ‖ f(x+h)- f_n(x+h)‖_p +  ‖ f_n(x+h)- f_n(x)‖_p +  ‖ f(x)- f_n(x)‖_p ≤ 3h → 0  $$