# How can I show that $\lim_{|h|\to 0}\| f(x+h)-f(x)\|_p = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

The following Exercise came from the lecture notes "Modern Real Analysis" by Ziemer, W. (Problem 6.34, pp. 213):

> If $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n), 1\leq p < \infty$, then prove $$\lim_{|h|\to 0}\| f(x+h)-f(x)\|_p = 0.$$ Also show that this result fails when $p=\infty$.

I don't know if the measure considered in the Lebesgue measure or this statement is valid in general measures for $\mathbb{R}^n$. I couldn't even start. Any hint will be really appreciated.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/842937/show-that-lim-r-to-0-t-rf%e2%88%92f-l-p-0?rq=1

Comment: @mathematician So it works only for the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: Note that smooth compactly supported functions are dense in $L^p$ if $p \in [1, \infty)$ but not for $p=\infty$.

Comment: $L^p$ spaces are usually defined with Lebesgue measure.  The theorem certainly works for some other measures.  I'm not sure off the top of my head exactly which measures satisfy the theorem.

Answer (score 0):

First suppose that $f$ is a continuous function with compact support.  If $h < 1$  then $|f(x) - f(x+h)|^p \le 2^p ||f||_{\infty}^p 1_{B(0,R)}$ for sufficiently large $R$.  Since $f$ is continuous and has compact support, $||f||_{\infty} < \infty$.  Since $|f(x+h) - f(x)| \to 0$ as $h \to 0$, the result holds by the dominated convergence theorem.

For general $f$, choose a sequence $f_k$ of continuous, compactly supported functions so that $f_k \to f$ in $L^p$.

For convenience, write $\tau_h(g)(x) = g(x +h)$

So, $||\tau_hf - f||_p = ||\tau_hf - \tau_hf_k + \tau_hf_k - f_k + f_k - f||_p \le ||\tau_hf - \tau_h f_k||_p + ||\tau_h f_k - f_k||_p  +||f_k - f||_p$

It's easy to check that $||\tau_h f - \tau_h f_k||_p = ||f - f_k||_p$.  Hence the first and third term tend to $0$ independent of $h$ as $k \to \infty$.  Since each $f_k$ is continuous and compactly supported, the second term tends to $0$ as $h \to 0$.

When $p = \infty$ consider the function $f := 1_{\{0\}}$.  Then $f(x+h) - f(x) = 1$ when $h = -x$, $-1$, when $x = 0$, and $0$ otherwise.  So $||\tau_h f - f||_{\infty} = 1$ for all $h$.

Comment: I think your counterexample is incorrect. The function $f$ vanish almost everywhere... Instead, take $f=\chi_{(-1,1)}$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Then, given $0<\delta<1$, take $h=\delta/2$ and conclude that $||\tau_h f - f||_{\infty} = 1$.