# What is the importance of the density of $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ and $L_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ on $L^p(\mathbb R^n)$, for every $1 \leq p < \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, examples-counterexamples, dense-subspaces

Consider the usual Lebesgue spaces $L^p(\mathbb R^n)$, for $1 \leqslant p < \infty$.

It is well known that both the spaces $L_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ of essentially bounded functions with compact support on $\mathbb R^n$ and $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ of infinitely differentiable functions with compact support on $\mathbb R^n$ are dense in $L^p(\mathbb R^n)$.

There are obviously many others dense subsets of $L^p(\mathbb R^n)$: for example, the space $C_c(\mathbb R^n)$ of continuous functions with compact support in $\mathbb R^n$ is also known to be dense in $L^p(\mathbb R^n)$. [In this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/847466/908975), the author provides a proof of a property on $L^p(\mathbb R)$ by using a density argument, using the set $C_c(\mathbb R)$. Clearly, the same proof works if we replace $C_c(\mathbb R)$ with $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$, for example.

Essentially, I would like to know examples of other results about $L^p(\mathbb R^n)$ spaces that can be proved using density arguments, specially using the spaces $L_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ and $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ that I mentioned above.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Usually stuff involving differential operators because it involves taking derivatives

Comment: @almosteverywhere That makes total sense, since on $C^\infty_c(\mathbb R^n)$ we can "freely" work with derivatives, but I was looking for something more specific. Do you have any specific result in mind?

Comment: Do you want an example only with $L^p$ spaces? For Sobolev spaces there will be many examples, e.g. $W^{k,p}$ can be approximated by $C_c^\infty$ (which is clearly false with $C_c$)

Comment: @almosteverywhere Yes, I am only interested in results on $L^p$ spaces. Basically I am looking for results that can be proved similarly to the result I linked but more relevant results, in some sense.

Comment: The Riemann-Lebesgue lemma can first be proved for $C^1$-functions using integration by parts, then one can extend to $L^1$ by density.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [*The boundedness of classical operators on variable $L^p$ spaces*](https://www.icmat.es/miembros/martell/Investigacion/CFMP-siovar.pdf).

Comment: This is **very good.** I happen to have read the book "Variable Lebesgue Spaces" (written by Cruz-Uribe and Fiorenza), which is a really good book and approaches the Hardy-Littlewood maximal operator on these spaces in an easier setting than the one you linked. Either way, I believe this is exactly what I was looking for without even knowing it. Thank you.